# How to keep search value after delete in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My Controller has search criteria

```
     // GET: 
    public ActionResult Index(int? page, string site, string user, string department,      string status, string TransactionDate)
    {
      /// Filter by search criteria
      return view(object.ToList());
    }
```

This is my delete action

```
// POST:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(string id = null)
    {
        var table = Table.Find(id);
        if (table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(table);
    }
```

How to keep search value and return the view filter by search value.

Thanks,
Si Thu

Comment: you can do that using ViewBag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC uses a TempData value that can be used as a bucket where you can dump data that is only needed for the following request.

So you'd use it like this in your action method:

```
TempData["searchId"] = id;
```

And retrieve it in your view using the same `TempData["searchId"]` syntax.

If my explanation doesn't explain it adequately (highly probable), then [this article](http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications) might offer a better idea.

Comment: The OP want to keep the data but the Tempdata is destroyed after a request.