# MVC How to keep search value when navigating between pages?

Tags: c#, html, .net, search, model-view-controller

I have a search box that searches by using EMPLID. Search works but if I go to any other page after doing search (Ex: If I switch to details page) and then navigate back to the page I did search on, It displays all the records. How can I keep the search criteria so that when I navigate between pages it shows information of that EMPLID?

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchString)
{

    var emp = from e in db.EMPLOYMENTs
              select e;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        emp = emp.Where(s => s.EMPLID.Contains(SearchString));
    }

    return View(emp);
}
```

My Layout:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" name="SearchString">
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: You'll likely want to stuff that data into a session variable, and then utilize that on each page if present.

Comment: i guess using cookies is best way to keep data while switching between pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TempData` for preserving the search string.

Add your SearchString in temp data like this-

```
TempData["SearchString"] = SearchString;
```

...and get back the value when required-

```
string searchString = TempData["SearchString"] as string;
```

Please refer this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dd394711%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article for more information on passing Data in an ASP.NET MVC Application

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: to use TempData or to use Session State.

**Follow the examples:**

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1074/aspnet-mvc-pass-values-temp-data-session-request

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/818493/MVC-Tempdata-Peek-and-Keep-confusion

[TempData keep() vs peek()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252888/tempdata-keep-vs-peek)

[How to keep search value after delete in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673290/how-to-keep-search-value-after-delete-in-mvc)

Comment: Thank you! Can you please provide examples?

Comment: Yes! One moment, i'm in cell phone.