# On clicking searchbox the data should remain same what we entered even after clicking button or reload the page

Tags: c#

I am using Hiddenvariable here and it is passed to controller from view.

```js
        @(Html.Search("ConfigurationSearch").Form("ConfigurationForm").Grid("gridConfiguration").ShowUnSelectAll(false))
        <div id="gridConfiguration"></div>
    </div>


    @Html.Hidden("hidSearchText")
    
     $(function () {
        $('#searchText_ConfigurationSearch').val("@TempData["SearchText"]");
    });

    $('.k-block').click(function () {
       $("#hidSearchText").val($("#searchText_ConfigurationSearch").val());
    });
```

Without using hiddenvariable Can we Implement this,Please suggest me?!

Comment: add proper tags

Comment: This same question has been asked before. Take a look here and see if that helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596194/mvc-how-to-keep-search-value-when-navigating-between-pages

Comment: I have used Temp Variable in controller its working ...but  I want Generic code  for all the searchbox.